# Windows 7 won't boot from GRUB (UEFI)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, uefi

everyone.
After having installed Ubuntu on my desktop Windows 7 won't run. There's a menuentry in the GRUB called "Windows 7" but when i press it nothing happens - the GRUB's menu just reappears.

I have EFI installed on my Sony Vaio S15 instead of BIOS. Here is the log from BOOT-REPAIR: http://paste.ubuntu.com/8173314/

I would appreciate any help u can give me.
Thanks in advance.
Alexey.

Answer (score 0):

Might be bug #1091464.  (Grub cannot boot Windows 8 with secure boot on) Try turning off secure boot and see if it works.

Comment: If the boot info is correct then: `SecureBoot disabled.` (line 666)

Answer (score 0):

Does the `Windows Boot Manager` option in the firmware still boot Windows? There are some `bkp`-prefixed files, that shouldn't exist in `EFI/Microsoft`, leading me to believe this is another case of boot-repair bringing more confusion to UEFI setups than necessary.

Backup the whole data on the partition, copy the `bkp` files back to where they should be (just remove the `bkp` prefix). Install a boot loader like rEFInd or gummiboot to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` and probably have a look at efibootmgr.

The boot-repair author doesn't care very much about how UEFI is intended to work. Which is infact harmful to users, but too many people are fine with that.